# manipulating webpages using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, html

For my question, I'll use an example. Let's say someone wanted to create an HTML form that would manipulate or create a webpage according to any request that is submitted in the form by a user. The form would utilize javascript to accomplish this. How would one be able to do this? Also, I'm not just looking for one color option; I want to create a form that changes/creates a bg color according to any request that is submitted in the form (i.e. not just the option of a red background, but multiple colors or decor options). Thanks for any info.

Brandon

Comment: I am looking at what you haven't tried. :|

Answer (score 0):

Usually form submission is only used for POST or GET communications with a server. If you want click functionality for some dynamic content use `<input type="button" onclick="jsfunction()">` or an anchor tag which calls jsfunction().

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="foo"> I'm a div! </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.backgroundColor="red";
```

JavaScript style commands are slightly different than the names of CSS properties. You can do a quick Google search to find a list of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can ease your work using jQuery:

javascript

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.backgroundColor="red";
```

becomes

```
$('#foo').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Another plus is, that the name of css attribute in latter is same as it is in HTML.

[Read more about jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)